# Need help understanding cross_val_score in sklearn python

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I am currently trying to implement K-FOLD cross validation in classification using sklearn in python. I understand the basic concept behind K-FOLD and cross validation. However, I dont understand what is the cross_val_score and what does it do and what role does the CV iteration have in getting the array of scores we get. Below are the examples from the official documentation page of sklearn.

```
**Example 1**
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
print(cross_val_score(lasso, X, y, cv=3))  
***OUPUT***
[0.33150734 0.08022311 0.03531764]
```

Taking a look at **Example 1**, the output generates 3 values in an array. I know that when we use kfold, n_split is the command that generates number of folds. So what does cv do in this example?

```
**My Code**
kf = KFold(n_splits=4,random_state=seed,shuffle=False)
print('Get_n_splits',kf.get_n_splits(X),'\n\n')
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
print('TRAIN:', train_index, 'TEST:', test_index)
x_train, x_test = df.iloc[train_index], df.iloc[test_index]
y_train, y_test = df.iloc[train_index], df.iloc[test_index]

print('\n\n')

# use train_test_split to split into training and testing data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

# fit / train the model using the training data
clf = BernoulliNB()
model = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_predicted = clf.predict(x_test)

scores = cross_val_score(model, df, y, cv=4)
print('\n\n')
print('Bernoulli Naive Bayes Classification Cross-validated Scores:', scores)
print('\n\n')
```

Looking at **My Code**, I am using 4 Fold cross validation for Bernoulli Naive Bayes Classifier and am using cv=4 in score as below :
    scores = cross_val_score(model, df, y, cv=4)
The above line gives me an array of 4 values. However, if I change it to cv= 8 as below :
    scores = cross_val_score(model, df, y, cv=8)
then an array of 8 values is generated as output. So again, what does cv do here.

I did read the documentation over and over again and searched numerous websites but since I am a newbie, I really don't understand what cv does and how the scores are generated.

Any and all help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cross_val_score` does the exact same thing in all your examples. It takes the features `df` and target `y`, splits into k-folds (which is the cv parameter), fits on the (k-1) folds and evaluates on the last fold. It does this k times, which is why you get k values in your output array.

Comment: The for loop : 

    `for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print('TRAIN:', train_index, 'TEST:', test_index)
    x_train, x_test = df.iloc[train_index], df.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = df.iloc[train_index], df.iloc[test_index]` splits the df into 4 folds, then trains 4 models, where each fold is then used as a testing set. So does the cv split the df into folds the same way as the df is split in the for loop or is it different? I ask for purposes of re-validation of accuracy of each fold. Also for confirmation `cross_val_score` calls `score` attribute of the model?

Answer (score 6):

In a K-FOLD Cross Validation, the following procedure is followed as follows:

1. Model is trained using K-1 of the folds as training data
2. Resulting Model is validated on the remaining data

This process is repeated K times and performance measure such as **"ACCURACY"** is computed at each step.

Please look at the image below to get a clear picture. It is taken from Cross Validation module  of Scikit-Learn.

[Cross Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmqc7.png)

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
>>> scores = cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
>>> scores                                              
array([0.96..., 1.  ..., 0.96..., 0.96..., 1.        ])
>>> print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
Accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.03)
```

Here the single mean Score is calculated. 
By default, the score computed at each CV iteration is the score method of the estimator.

I have taken help from the links mentioned below.

1. "https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score"
2. 'https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation'

Answer (score 0):

Cross Validation involves splitting the data into a training set and a validation set. The model is trained on the training set and then evaluated on the validation set. This process is repeated multiple times, with the model being trained on different subsets of the data each time. The final evaluation score is the average of the scores from the individual cross-validation folds.